# Jquery 3.1.0 ( upgraded from 2.2.0) - ID Selector - Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#"

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

I have upgraded to latest version of Jquery 3.1.0 from 2.2.0. We also use Kendo UI in our view. First thing i noticed with the upgrade is IDSelector for kendo grid is not working and throwing "**Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #**" error.

```
var gridDataSource = $("#gridList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
```

The stacktrace is

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
   at Sizzle.error (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:1532:2)
   at Sizzle.tokenize (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:2181:2)
   at Sizzle.select (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:2609:3)
   at Sizzle (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:890:2)
   at find (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:2859:4)
   at jQuery.fn.init (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js:2969:5)
   at R.fn.init (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:26:8407)
   at R (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:25:5033)
   at _parentWidget (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:38:21862)
   at setDataSource (http://localhost:6128/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:38:17716)
```

I looked up different forums and couldn't find any thing related to this error.

Appreciate any help on this error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Kendo Ui controls aren't compatible with jquery 3.x or later versions

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-jquery-versions